# Class extending Ext.data.Model - methods .get and .set behaves differently compare to getter/setter

Tags: extjs, extjs4

When i am creating the model by extending "Ext.data.Model" class, getter/setter methods are behaving differently than default .get and .set methods available from data.Model

It seems like one can either use getter/setter methods or .get/.set methods, because they seem to be maintaining separate set of fields.

Why is it so? Parden me if question looks silly, i am learning Ext JS an trying to understand how it works. I am using library version ExtJS4.2.1

Class

```
Ext.define("Ext.model.Invoice", {
        extend : "Ext.data.Model",
        fields : [{name : 'id'}, {name : 'taxId'}, {name : 'name'}],
        config : {
            name : 'Tejas',
            taxId : '23746'
        },
        constructor : function(config) {
            this.callParent(arguments);
            this.initConfig(config);
        }
    });
```

HTML

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    var invoice = Ext.create("Ext.model.Invoice");

    console.log("Before, invoice.get('name'):", invoice.get('name'));
    console.log("Before, invoice.getName():", invoice.getName());

    //Modifying name
    invoice.setName("Mr. Smith");
    invoice.set("name","Mr. Tony");
    console.log("Updating names using setName and set('name')");

    console.log("After, invoice.get('name'):", invoice.get('name'));
    console.log("After, invoice.getName():", invoice.getName());

});
```

OUTPUT

```
Before, invoice.get('name'):
Before, invoice.getName(): Tejas
Updating names using setName and set('name')
After, invoice.get('name'): Mr. Tony
After, invoice.getName(): Mr. Smith
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `config` configuration property you are defining list of configuration options with their default values, but not default model data.

When instance of object is creating, for each property defined in `config` is automatically created setter and getter method, and object property with same name as config property.

`Ext.data.Model` stores model data in its private `data` property. For example you can try to dump model data for `name` field by:

```
console.log(invoice.data.name);
```

So by setter and getter you access object property, but by `model.get()` and `model.set()` you access model's data stored in model's private `data` property.